# Loading kendo grid with Behavioral Subject

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I am having a problem loading the kendo grid with a Behavioral subject. I seeem to get the data fine from the service, but for some reason it is not bound to the grid. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a plunker for the same [Kendo Grid with Subject](http://plnkr.co/edit/XHneCVKWjPbhlTcxn35A?p=preview)

this is linked to the SO - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41882998/dynamically-load-details-grid-in-the-master-details-grid

Comment: Meh !! fixed it. Calling the wrong service.